# How to delete a file after processing an algorithm in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, python, vector, multipart

I am trying to delete an intermediate file ("Temp_merged.shp") after running the singleparts to multiparts algorithm in QGIS 2.18.

```
   import glob, os, processing
   path_to_shp = "C:/Temp/Tracks/"
   os.chdir(path_to_shp)

   for fname in glob.glob("Temp_merged.shp"):
        merger = "Temp_merged.shp"
        processing.runalg("qgis:singlepartstomultipart",merger,"Unique","Multipart.shp", progress=None)

   del merger
   os.remove("Temp_merged.shp")
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Temp_merged.shp' See log for more details

How can I end the processing.runalg to delete the intermediate shapefile?